# when before or after hover then color is not work

Tags: html, css

When i am trying to hover with (Using before after hover) in my price table section then background is changed but color is not works.

## Here is my markup

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4- col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <div class="single-price-table price-tbl-active">
               <div class="price-header">
                 <h3>Startup</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="price-content pptb-30">
                 <h4> <sub> $ </sub> 279  </h4>
                 <span>/month</span>
                 <ul>
                   <li>20 Users</li>
                   <li>Unlimited Plan</li>
                   <li>Custom Design</li>
                   <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                   <li>Unlimited Time</li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="price-footer">
                 <a href="">Get Started Now</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

## Here is my style-sheet code:

```
.single-price-table{
 position:relative;
}
    .single-price-table:first-child::before {
      background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      content: "";
      height: 10%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      color:#ffffff;
    }
    .single-price-table:hover:first-child::before{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .single-price-table:last-child::after {
      background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      content: "";
      height: 10%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      color:#ffffff;
    }
    .single-price-table:hover:last-child::after{
      opacity: 1;

    }
```

Comment: .single-price-table:hover:first-child::before {   not working      }

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.single-price-table:first-child:hover::before {
```

not

```
.single-price-table:hover:first-child::before {
```

First find the selector then apply the hover

```css
.single-price-table {
  position: relative;
}

.single-price-table:first-child::before {
  background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.single-price-table:first-child:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.single-price-table:last-child::after {
  background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  content: "";
  height: 10%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.single-price-table:last-child:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4- col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="single-price-table price-tbl-active">
    <div class="price-header">
      <h3>Startup</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="price-content pptb-30">
      <h4> <sub> $ </sub> 279 </h4>
      <span>/month</span>
      <ul>
        <li>20 Users</li>
        <li>Unlimited Plan</li>
        <li>Custom Design</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Unlimited Time</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="price-footer">
      <a href="">Get Started Now</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add color to `h3`

```
.single-price-table:hover:first-child h3{
color:#fff;
}
```

and `z-index` to before element.

```css
.single-price-table{
 position:relative;
}
    .single-price-table:first-child::before {
      background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      content: "";
      height: 10%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      color:#ffffff;
      z-index:-1
    }
    .single-price-table:hover:first-child h3{
    color:#fff;
    }
    .single-price-table:hover:first-child::before{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .single-price-table:last-child::after {
      background: #283754 none repeat scroll 0 0;
      content: "";
      height: 10%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      color:#ffffff;
    }
    .single-price-table:hover:last-child::after{
      opacity: 1;

    }
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4- col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <div class="single-price-table price-tbl-active">
               <div class="price-header">
                 <h3>Startup</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="price-content pptb-30">
                 <h4> <sub> $ </sub> 279  </h4>
                 <span>/month</span>
                 <ul>
                   <li>20 Users</li>
                   <li>Unlimited Plan</li>
                   <li>Custom Design</li>
                   <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
                   <li>Unlimited Time</li>
                 </ul>
               </div>
               <div class="price-footer">
                 <a href="">Get Started Now</a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```